# Limpar buffer scanner Fujitsu Fi-7160 em c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scanner

Estou trabalhando em um projeto da Empresa, C# Windows Form e ainda sou iniciante na plataforma dot net.
Eu gostaria de saber com os amigos de profissão, se existe alguma forma de eu poder limpar o buffer do Scanner Fujitsu Fi-7160, depois de digitalizar cerca de 1500 folhas, pois sempre a aplicação apresenta mensagem de falta de memória, buffer cheio e para poder voltar a digitalizar, é necessário fechar e abrir novamente a aplicação.
Já baixei, instalei e atualizei todos os drivers do fabricante, porém ainda sem sucesso. Já busquei soluções direto no site do Fabricante, porém sem sucesso também.
Até onde eu pesquisei, a aplicação é 32 bits, rodando no windows 10 64 bits, o scanner utiliza a porta hdmi do notebook, a aplicação se comunica com o scanner através do programa PaperStream IP (TWAIN).
Desde já eu agradeço, caso os amigos consigam me ajudar com alguma orientação.

```
private string scannearParaArquivo(string arquivo, bool mostraConfig)
    {
        //
        string ret = "";
        AcquireModalState acquireModalState;
        using (DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager())
        {
            deviceManager.Open();

            Device device = deviceManager.Devices.Current;



            try
            {
                // open the device 
                device.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Concat("Não foi possivel acessar o scanner: ",ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            try
            {
                // set acquisition parameters 


                device.ShowUI = mostraConfig;
                device.DisableAfterAcquire = true;
                device.TransferMode = TransferMode.Memory;
                device.FileFormat = TwainImageFileFormat.Tiff;


                device.AcquiredImages.TiffMultiPage = false;
                device.AcquiredImages.TiffCompression = TiffCompression.Auto;

                device.AcquiredImages.AutoClean = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Concat("Erro na configuração do Scanner: ", ex.Message.ToString());
            }


            // set filename the first acquired image
            imageIndex++;
            device.FileName = string.Concat(arquivo, imageIndex.ToString("00000000"), ".tif");

            bool atingiuMaximoDocto = false;

            // acquire images from device 
            acquireModalState = AcquireModalState.None;
            do
            {
                int ponto = 0;
                try
                {
                    acquireModalState = device.AcquireModal();
                    switch (acquireModalState)
                    {
                        case AcquireModalState.ImageAcquired:
                            //
                            ponto = 1;
                            string i = device.FileName;
                            device.AcquiredImages.Last.Save(i);
                            mostraCaptura(imageIndex, i);
                            //set filename for next acquired image 
                            imageIndex++;
                            device.FileName = string.Concat(arquivo, imageIndex.ToString("00000000"), ".tif");
                            GC.Collect(); // 10/07/2018
                            break;
                        case AcquireModalState.ScanCompleted:
                            // Fim de captura saida normal
                            // close the device 
                            ponto = 2;
                            device.Dispose();
                            device.Close();
                            // close the device manager 
                            device.AcquiredImages.Clear();
                            deviceManager.Dispose();
                            deviceManager.Close();
                            GC.Collect(); // 10/07/2018
                            break;
                        case AcquireModalState.ScanCanceled:
                            // Fim da captura por atingir maximo de documento ou por cancelamento
                            ponto = 3;
                            if (atingiuMaximoDocto == true)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Quantidade de documentos digitalizados ultrapassou o limite. \n Feche este lote e inicie um novo Lote. \n\n Atenção, verifique os ultimos documento digitalizado.\n\n\n Digitalização encerrada, confira os ultimos documentos", "Aviso do Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            }
                            // close the device 
                            device.Dispose();
                            device.Close();
                            // close the device manager 
                            deviceManager.Dispose();
                            deviceManager.Close();
                            GC.Collect(); // 10/07/2018
                            break;
                        case AcquireModalState.ScanFailed:
                            // close the device 
                            ponto = 4;
                            device.Dispose();
                            device.Close();
                            // close the device manager 
                            deviceManager.Dispose();
                            deviceManager.Close();
                            GC.Collect(); // 10/07/2018
                            ret = "Verifique se há documento";
                            break;
                    }
                    if (imageIndex > 111 & atingiuMaximoDocto == false)
                    {
                        if (device != null)
                        {
                            // send command to cancel the transfer  
                            if (device.State == DeviceState.Transferring || device.State == DeviceState.TransferReady)
                            {
                                ponto = 5;
                                device.CancelTransfer();
                            }
                        }
                        atingiuMaximoDocto = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Erro inesperado na Captura
                    ret = ex.Message.ToString();
                    LogSistema.logProcessamento(string.Concat("Erro inesperado na captura no ponto ", ponto.ToString()), pathLog);
                    LogSistema.logProcessamento(string.Concat("Pasta ", arquivo, " - " , this.labNumeroEquipamento.Text), pathLog);
                    LogSistema.logProcessamento(ret, pathLog);
                    LogSistema.logProcessamento("======================================================================", pathLog);
                }

            }
            while (acquireModalState != AcquireModalState.None);
            imageIndex--;
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Onde é armazenado esse buffer? Se for no GC, você pode limpar com `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta o código que digitaliza.

Comment: @CypherPotato amanhã logo pela manhã no serviço, eu irei postar o trecho do código que está digitalizando os documentos e mais informações sobre o meu ambiente.
vou verificar direitinho onde é armazenado esse buffer e depois informo a você. Desde já eu agradeço pelos feedback dos amigos.

Comment: gostaria de ver de onde vem o `Device` e `DeviceManager`, são de alguma biblioteca ? Quando implementei digitalização, utilizei `TwainDotNet`. Pra mim funciona tranquilo, só não testei com 1500 páginas rs

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu estou usando a biblioteca **Vintasoft.Twain.dll**. Se não for muito abuso da minha parte, você conseguiria me passar o link de onde eu consigo baixar essa Biblioteca TwainDotNet que você mencionou. Eu agradeço muito pelo tempo que você dedicou para tentar me ajudar.

Comment: @GabrielFilipeCarvalho salvo engano, consegui em algum projeto no `codeproject.com`. Mas não lembro. De qualquer forma, enviei para o git: https://github.com/rovannlinhalis/SOpt/tree/master/Teste%20Scanner

Comment: Maravilha @RovannLinhalis eu te agradeço pela gentileza. Vou baixar e usar essa biblioteca e vou me programar para postar uma resposta sobre o teste ainda hoje. Novamente eu agradeço.